# What happens at the system level on an incoming call?

Tags: android, telephony

I've downloaded the entire source code for the master branch from
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master, and am trying to decipher the chain of events on an incoming call.

I assume that the ACTION_ANSWER intent is started but beyond that don't know what happens before or after.

Can anyone help?

Comment: At what system level? There is a huge chain of things involved: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/telephony.html

Comment: yes I'm familiar with the RIL. Primarily concerned with the ApplicationFramework layer and up since that is all Java and easily modded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's begin by looking at [CallNotifier](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/CallNotifier.java):

> /**  * Phone app module that listens for phone state changes and
>   various other  * events from the telephony layer, and triggers any
>   resulting UI behavior  * (like starting the Ringer and Incoming Call
>   UI, playing in-call tones,  * updating notifications, writing call log
>   entries, etc.)  */

One of the messages that this Handler responds to is: `CallStateMonitor.PHONE_NEW_RINGING_CONNECTION`:

```
case CallStateMonitor.PHONE_NEW_RINGING_CONNECTION:
    log("RINGING... (new)");
    onNewRingingConnection((AsyncResult) msg.obj);
    mSilentRingerRequested = false;
    break;
```

`onNewRingingConnection(AsyncResult)` eventually (and, in general case) calls `ringAndNotifyOfIncomingCall(Connection c)`:

```
private void ringAndNotifyOfIncomingCall(Connection c) {
    if (PhoneUtils.isRealIncomingCall(c.getState())) {
        mRinger.ring();
    } else {
        if (VDBG) log("- starting call waiting tone...");
            if (mCallWaitingTonePlayer == null) {
                mCallWaitingTonePlayer = new InCallTonePlayer(
                                         InCallTonePlayer.TONE_CALL_WAITING);
                mCallWaitingTonePlayer.start();
            }
    }

    // CallModeler.onNewRingingConnection(Connection)
    mCallModeler.onNewRingingConnection(c);
}
```

`CallModeler.onNewRingingConnection(Connection)` ([Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/CallModeler.java#onNewRingingConnection)) notifies attached listeners:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mListeners.size(); ++i) {
    mListeners.get(i).onIncoming(call);
}
```

These listeners implement `CallModeler.Listener` interface. [CallHandlerServiceProxy](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/CallHandlerServiceProxy.java) is one such listener, and its `onIncoming(Call)` callback fires `CallHandlerServiceProxy.processIncoming(Call)`:

```
private void processIncoming(Call call) {
    ....
    // ICallHandlerService
    mCallHandlerServiceGuarded.onIncoming(call,
                   RejectWithTextMessageManager.loadCannedResponses());
    ....
}
```

[CallHandlerService](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/InCallUI/src/com/android/incallui/CallHandlerService.java) defines a `ICallHandlerService.Stub` member and its `onIncoming(Call, List<String>)` method looks like:

```
@Override
public void onIncoming(Call call, List<String> textResponses) {
    ....
    mMainHandler.sendMessage(mMainHandler.obtainMessage(
                   ON_UPDATE_CALL_WITH_TEXT_RESPONSES, incomingCall));
    ....
}
```

This is how `mMainHandler` handles case `ON_UPDATE_CALL_WITH_TEXT_RESPONSES`:

```
case ON_UPDATE_CALL_WITH_TEXT_RESPONSES:
    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Call, List<String>> entry
                   = (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Call, List<String>>) msg.obj;
    Log.i(TAG, "ON_INCOMING_CALL: " + entry.getKey());

    // CallList
    mCallList.onIncoming(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    break;
```

[CallList](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/InCallUI/src/com/android/incallui/CallList.java) keeps a list of listeners that implement `CallList.Listener`, and fires their `onIncomingCall(Call)` event from its `CallList.onIncoming(Call, List<String>)` method.

Now, let's look at [InCallPresenter](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/InCallUI/src/com/android/incallui/InCallPresenter.java):

> /**  * Takes updates from the CallList and notifies the InCallActivity
>   (UI)  * of the changes.  * Responsible for starting the activity for a
>   new call and finishing the activity when all calls  * are
>   disconnected.  * Creates and manages the in-call state and provides a
>   listener pattern for the presenters  * that want to listen in on the
>   in-call state changes.  * TODO: This class has become more of a state
>   machine at this point.  Consider renaming.  */

`InCallPresenter` implements `CallList.Listener` interface, and is responsible for launching `InCallActivity` that provides the UI for all phone related operations. The following comment (taken from `InCallPresenter.startOrFinishUi(InCallState)`) brings the above-mentioned chain of events together:

```
/* A new Incoming call means that the user needs to be notified of the
   the call (since it wasn't them who initiated it).  We do this 
   through full  screen notifications and happens indirectly through {@link 
   StatusBarListener}. The process for incoming calls is as follows:

   1) CallList          - Announces existence of new INCOMING call
   2) InCallPresenter   - Gets announcement and calculates that the new 
                          InCallState should be set to INCOMING.
   3) InCallPresenter   - This method is called to see if we need to 
                          start or finish the app given the new state.
   4) StatusBarNotifier - Listens to InCallState changes. InCallPresenter 
                          calls StatusBarNotifier explicitly to issue a 
                          FullScreen Notification that will either start the
                          InCallActivity or show the user a top-level 
                          notification dialog if the user is in 
                          an immersive app. That notification can also start 
                          the InCallActivity.         
   5) InCallActivity    - Main activity starts up and at the end of its 
                          onCreate will call InCallPresenter::setActivity() 
                          to let the presenter know that start-up is complete.
                  [ AND NOW YOU'RE IN THE CALL. voila! ] */
```

I hope this answers your question, or at the very least, shows you where to look. Feel free to correct anything I overlooked/misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this [Grep code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/phone/InCallScreen.java) InCallScreen.java

```
   else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)) {
        internalAnswerCall();
        app.setRestoreMuteOnInCallResume(false);
        return InCallInitStatus.SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a much older version of Android. What about KitKat? It seems that the InCall Screen has been changed

Answer (score 1):

Hope below Code Help you.

```
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
         super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
         switch(state){
         case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
             //Not in call: Play music

             break;
         case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
             //A call is dialing, active or on hold

             break;
         case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
             //Incoming call: Pause music

             break;

         }            
    }
```

The google reference is
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html